# margin-top displayed differently in Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am having problem with positioning two table rows next to each other. While I am able to achieve what I want with setting margin-top to specific value, the layout is different in all four major browsers.
This is what I have for example in FF:

[image]

Using the same styling this is what I have in IE:

[image]

This is what I have for CSS rule for the 2nd row:

```
.UserProfile {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-375px;
    margin-left:400px;    
}
```

Now shifting the margin-top value to some other value will change the layout, and as it is currently it looks good only in FF.

I placed the markup and the CSS in JS Fiddle and it can be found at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/laziale/2Q7AN/2/

For quick reference, the table where the markup is placed can be found here:

```
<table>                                                      
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table id="CompanyProfileTable" >
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td align="left" colspan="2">
                        <span class="formtitle23">Company Profile</span>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Company Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCompanyName"
                            ErrorMessage="Company Name is required." ToolTip="Company Name is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Website:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyWebsite" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>                                                                          
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Street Address:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreetAddress1" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStreetAddress1"
                            ErrorMessage="Street Address is required." ToolTip="Street Address is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Street Address Line 2:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreetAddress2" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Country:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" CssClass="formfield FirstName_TD" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCountry"
                            DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="CountryID" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Province:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateProvince" runat="server" OnDataBound="DropDownList2_DataBound"
                            AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceStateProvince" DataTextField="Description"
                            DataValueField="StateProvinceID" CssClass="formfield">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0" ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="ddlStateProvince" ErrorMessage="Province is required." ToolTip="Province is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        City:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" OnDataBound="DropDownList3_DataBound"
                            AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCity" DataTextField="Description"
                            DataValueField="CityID" CssClass="formfield" style="overflow:auto;">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0" ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="ddlCity" ErrorMessage="City is required." ToolTip="City is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Postal Code:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalCode" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalCode"
                            ErrorMessage="Postal Code is required." ToolTip="Postal Code is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Business Phone:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessPhone1" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBusinessPhone1"
                            ErrorMessage="Business Phone is required." Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="Business Phone is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        Ext:<asp:TextBox ID="BusinessPhoneExt1TextBox" runat="server" CssClass="ManageUsers_UserName" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessPhoneExt1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Company Logo:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuLogo" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="color:red;">Company Logo Limit Size: 100kb</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="UserProfile" style="float:right; vertical-align:top;">
        <td colspan="2" class="rightPR">
            <table id="UserProfileTable">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="rightPR">
                        <br />
                        <span class="formtitle23">User Profile</span>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR FirstName_TD rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">First Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                            ErrorMessage="First Name is required." Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="First Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                                                 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Last Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName"
                            ErrorMessage="Last Name is required." Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="Last Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                                                   
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                            ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                            ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                            ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required."
                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                            ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Question"
                            ErrorMessage="Security question is required." ToolTip="Security question is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Answer"
                            ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." ToolTip="Security answer is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">User Type:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoles" runat="server" CssClass="formfield">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr">
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Will you be the administrator of the company?</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50px;">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdministrator" runat="server" CssClass="formfield">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="true" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="false" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                         <img alt="ToolTip" src="../Images/ico-question-mark.jpg" onmousemove="move(this,event);" onmouseout="out(this);"/><br /><div id="tip" style="margin-left:60px;margin-top:-168px;">
    <img src="../Images/arrowtipright.gif" alt="" class="createResumeTipArrow2" />
    One user must be the administrator for the company and will have the ability to add or delete other users on the same company profile.
</div>                                                          
                    </td>
                     
                </tr>                                                                  
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="ErrorMessage GenericCenter">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" DisplayMode="BulletList" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"
                runat="server" HeaderText="There are the following error(s) on the page:" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="ErrorMessage GenericCenter">
            <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Post the generated HTML output please, we're not going to convert the `asp` blocks to HTML, nor the JSFiddle.

Comment: Looks like maybe a float not being cleared to me. But anyways ..navigators all use various initial values for margins & stuff on elements. Best bet is to use a reset css or normalize css to have constant values across the various browsers to start with

Comment: @HashemQolami jsfiddle updated with generated HTML. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Ehm... do you really need tables nested 6 levels deep?

Comment: @MrLister what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using different rows when you can put your table in cell also? There is no issue of margin.

You can try this HTML:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table id="CompanyProfileTable" >
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td align="left" colspan="2">
                        <span class="formtitle23">Company Profile</span>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Company Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCompanyName"
                            ErrorMessage="Company Name is required." ToolTip="Company Name is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Website:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyWebsite" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>                                                                          
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Street Address:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreetAddress1" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStreetAddress1"
                            ErrorMessage="Street Address is required." ToolTip="Street Address is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Street Address Line 2:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreetAddress2" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Country:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" CssClass="formfield FirstName_TD" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCountry"
                            DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="CountryID" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Province:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateProvince" runat="server" OnDataBound="DropDownList2_DataBound"
                            AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceStateProvince" DataTextField="Description"
                            DataValueField="StateProvinceID" CssClass="formfield">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0" ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="ddlStateProvince" ErrorMessage="Province is required." ToolTip="Province is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        City:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" OnDataBound="DropDownList3_DataBound"
                            AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCity" DataTextField="Description"
                            DataValueField="CityID" CssClass="formfield" style="overflow:auto;">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0" ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="ddlCity" ErrorMessage="City is required." ToolTip="City is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Postal Code:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalCode" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalCode"
                            ErrorMessage="Postal Code is required." ToolTip="Postal Code is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        Business Phone:
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessPhone1" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBusinessPhone1"
                            ErrorMessage="Business Phone is required." Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="Business Phone is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        Ext:<asp:TextBox ID="BusinessPhoneExt1TextBox" runat="server" CssClass="ManageUsers_UserName" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessPhoneExt1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Company Logo:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuLogo" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="color:red;">Company Logo Limit Size: 100kb</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    
        <td colspan="2" class="rightPR">
            <table id="UserProfileTable">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="rightPR">
                        <br />
                        <span class="formtitle23">User Profile</span>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR FirstName_TD rightPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">First Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightPR">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                            ErrorMessage="First Name is required." Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="First Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Last Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName"
                            ErrorMessage="Last Name is required." Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="Last Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                                                   
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                            ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                            ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                            ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required."
                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                            ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Question"
                            ErrorMessage="Security question is required." ToolTip="Security question is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server" CssClass="formfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Answer"
                            ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." ToolTip="Security answer is required."
                            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">User Type:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoles" runat="server" CssClass="formfield">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr">
                    <td class="leftPR">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Will you be the administrator of the company?</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50px;">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdministrator" runat="server" CssClass="formfield">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="true" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="false" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                         <img alt="ToolTip" src="../Images/ico-question-mark.jpg" onmousemove="move(this,event);" onmouseout="out(this);"/><br /><div id="tip" style="margin-left:60px;margin-top:-168px;">
    <img src="../Images/arrowtipright.gif" alt="" class="createResumeTipArrow2" />
    One user must be the administrator for the company and will have the ability to add or delete other users on the same company profile.
</div>                                                          
                    </td>

                </tr>                                                                  
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="ErrorMessage GenericCenter">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" DisplayMode="BulletList" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"
                runat="server" HeaderText="There are the following error(s) on the page:" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="ErrorMessage GenericCenter">
            <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that almost worked, please check the jsfiddle, I just need to adjust the right side a bit more and align with the left one http://jsfiddle.net/laziale/2Q7AN/3/